# How do I stockpile policies in games with 'enable policy saving' on?

Tags: civilization-5

Whenever I play a game with the option 'enable policy saving' turned on, I still can't figure out how to not invest in a policy as the button for 'NEXT TURN' is replaced with 'ADOPT POLICY'.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you hover over the button, you should see a handy tooltip:

[image]

As the tooltip suggests, right clicking will dismiss the Adopt Policy prompt without having to select a policy.